# How to invalidate selected session programmatically?

Tags: java, session, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I'm trying to invalidate selected session (with given sessionId) from my web application runing on Jboss 4.2. Everything works perfect from JMX console but
I don't know how to do the same in java code. Here is what i have already created:

```
MBeanServer server=MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("jboss.web:host=localhost,path=/,type=Manager");

ManagerBase manager = (ManagerBase)MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(server, objectName, Manager.class, false);
manager.expireSession("sessionID");
```

But this code gives this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy574 cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase
```

Can You help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to collect the session in a map check following link :

- [How can i load Java HttpSession from JSESSIONID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092363/how-can-i-load-java-httpsession-from-jsessionid/3092495#3092495)
- [Find number of active sessions created from a given client IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679465/find-number-of-active-sessions-created-from-a-given-client-ip/3679783#3679783)
- [How to easily implement "who is online" in Grails or Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271676/how-to-easily-implement-who-is-online-in-grails-or-java-application/3271748#3271748)

Comment: I want to invalidate any session (based on the specified `JSESSIONID`). Your solution invalidates only current session (session to which caller is connected).

Comment: I was wondering about performance in Your scenario. This Map will be very large. What do You thing about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for the answer. That snippet works for me:

```
        MBeanServer server = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        ObjectName objectName=new ObjectName("jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/test,host=default-host");

        // declare signature of the parameter
        String[] sig = { "java.lang.String"};
        // your session id e.g. A7rOCAlFa+9uCeUfYNjJpd3r.undefined
        Object[] opArgs1 = { sessionID };
        // call the method
        String value = (String) server.invoke(objectName, "expireSession",
                opArgs1, sig);
```

I am working on JBoss-7.1.1.Final. My application is called "test", hence the context root "/test". You should create objectName with name of your application.