# How to invalidate particular sessions?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to invalidate few particular sessions that i saved using "httpsession".Is it possible to invalidate selected sessions and keep the remaining sessions alive?

Comment: what do you mean by selected sessions?

Comment: Suppose a client has name, age and number attributes.Suppose I have saved these in session as setsession("name",name),setsession("age",age),setsession("number",number). So how do I invalidate only the name session and keep the rest alive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two way to invalidate session in servlet/jsp

1--session.invalidate();

2--session.removeAttribute("xyz");

to invalidate particular session we use 2nd option instead of xyz you put any session name there

Comment: (2) is nonsense. The attributes of a session are not sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just call `HttpSession.invalidate()` or `HttpSession.logout()` (Servlet 3.0).

Comment: wouldn't it invalidate all the sessions of the related client ?

Comment: @chaodee No, it will invalidate the session you call it on.

Comment: it is useful when you want to invalidate whole Session. but suppose i want to remove particular session or variable from session than what. If you have better way than session.removeAttribute("xyz") than explain.  but remember i want just remove variable from session not whole session.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is best way to invalidate particular session not completely

```
session.invalidate();
```

and

```
session.removeAttribute("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a method which does invalidate session with given sessionID:

```
public void expireSessionWithId(String sessionID)
{  
     try { 
        MBeanServer server = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        ObjectName objectName=new ObjectName("jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/test,host=default-host");

        // declare signature of the parameter
        String[] sig = { "java.lang.String"};
        // declare parameter
        Object[] opArgs1 = { sessionID };
        // call the method
        String value = (String) server.invoke(objectName, "expireSession",
                opArgs1, sig);

        System.out.println(value);
    } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
        //handle the exception
    } catch (InstanceNotFoundException e) {
        //handle the exception
    } catch (ReflectionException e) {
        //handle the exception
    } catch (MBeanException e) {
        //handle the exception
    }

}
```

I am working on JBoss-7.1.1.Final. My application is called "test", hence the context root "/test". You should create objectName with name of your application.

Comment: Your answer is JBoss-specific, and JBoss is not mentioned in the question. -1

Answer (score -1):

'EJP's' solution works perfect for current session. But if You want to invalidate any session (based on the specified JSESSIONID) here is the answer: [How to invalidate selected session programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724004/how-to-invalidate-selected-session-programmatically)

Comment: Can You tell me how to do it? I had the same problem month (or two) ago. So the question is: How can I invalidate session with selected id (i.e 'xyz') from different one session.

Comment: Get the session, as shown in your link, and then call one of the APIs mentioned in my answer.